# Parse country from address (last word of comma separated strings)

Tags: parsing, google-sheets

In a Google Spreadsheet, I have a list of thousands of addresses in column A that look like this:

```
1 Park View Road, Prestwich, Manchester M25, UK
Calle Venerable Juan de Santiago, 3, 14010 Córdoba, Córdoba, Spain
Rua Desembargador Motta, 3351-3447 - Água Verde, Matriz, Curitiba - PR, Brazil
Via Giuseppe De Paoli, 4, 16143 Genova, Italy
Wemmelse Steenweg 218, 1090 Jette, Belgium
Lekki - Epe Express Road, Lekki, Nigeria
```

The country is always listed at the end of the address. How can I parse the country from each address and put it into column B?

Comment: Is this really on-topic?

Comment: why not using a CSV operations?

Comment: @Abdelouahab Does Google Spreadsheet even have CSV operations? My guess is 'probably not'.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12119?hl=en

Comment: @pnuts I asked via a custom flag but the moderator declined it and obviously can't be asked to do their job properly as they wrote 'use the normal close flags'. ***How can I use a close flag to ask a question?!?***

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in row 2, then in B2 try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),regexextract(A2:A, "\s(\w+)$"),))
```

or depending on your locale:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A);regexextract(A2:A; "\s(\w+)$");))
```

An other option may be:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),trim(regexextract(A2:A, "\s[^,]*$")),))
```

Comment: This works! I think there's a slight issue though. I noticed that if the country has two or more words, only the last word was parsed. So in the case of "Puerto Rico", only "Rico" was produced. And in other cases, for example if the country is "Côte d'Ivoire", the result was #N/A. Thanks though. I think this will work.

Comment: Hi Grabreil, I added another option in my answe. You may want to try that one, too...

Answer (score 0):

Another way, both copied down to suit:

In B1:  `=HLOOKUP("zzzzz",C1:Z1,1)`
In C1:  `=split(A1,",")`